# Should the width of the navigator.notification.alert window change depending on the device

Tags: cordova

I'm curious about something that I just noticed.

I'm using XCode 4.5.1 with PhoneGap 1.9.

The size of the navigator.notification.window doesn't change when I switch between the iPad and iPhone simulators.
I would have thought the window would have been larger when the app is running on a larger device.

Thanks
Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Cordova Docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#Notification):

> notification.alert: [... ] Most Cordova implementations use a native dialog box for this feature

This includes iOS, which means that Cordova simply displays a native alert box. These are the same "size" across all devices, regardless of the device's screen size. You can try this for yourself in the simulator, for example if you enter an invalid protocol in Safari ("qqq://test"). The alert window that appears is exactly the same regardless of device!